# I have a swift file for "firebase user" called Fuser.swift which has a class called FUser Contains all info I want to save in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

here is the code which the problem in FUser :

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'FUser' with an argument list of type '(_objectId: String, _pushId: String, _createdAt: Date, _updatedAt: Date, _firstname: String, _lastname: String)'

```
class func registerUserWith(email: String, password: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void ) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) {
        (firuser, error) in

        if error != nil {

            completion(error)
            return
        }

        let fUser = FUser(_objectId: firuser!.user.uid, _pushId: "", _createdAt: Date(), _updatedAt: Date(), _firstname: firstName, _lastname: lastName)

            saveUserLocally(fUser: fUser)
            saveUserInBackground(fUser: fUser)
            completion(error)
        }

}
```

& Here is The File If You Want To See something :

import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth

```
class FUser  {

let objectId :  String
var pushId : String?

let createdAt : Date
var updatedAt : Date

var coins : Int
var company : String
var firstName : String
var lastName : String
var fullName : String
var avatar : String
var phoneNumber : String
var additionalPhoneNumber : String
var isAgent : Bool
var favouriteProperities : [String]

init(_objectId :  String ,_pushId : String?,_createdAt : Date,_updatedAt : Date,_coins : Int,_firstName: String,_lastName:String,_fullName:String,_avatar:String,_phoneNumber:String) {
    objectId = _objectId
    pushId = _pushId
    createdAt = _createdAt
    updatedAt = _updatedAt
    coins = _coins
    company = ""
    firstName = _firstName
    lastName = _lastName
    fullName = _firstName + " " + _lastName
    avatar = _avatar
    phoneNumber = _phoneNumber
    additionalPhoneNumber = ""
    isAgent = false
    favouriteProperities = []
}

init(_dictionary : NSDictionary) {
   ///...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your init you have _ attached to the word next to it.
Change it to

```
init(_ objectId :  String ,_ pushId : String?,_ createdAt : Date,_ updatedAt : Date,_ coins : Int, _firstName: String,_ lastName:String,_ fullName:String,_ avatar:String,_ phoneNumber:String)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an init method which doesn't exist.

You call:

```
init(_objectId: firuser!.user.uid, 
_pushId: "", 
_createdAt: Date(), 
_updatedAt: Date(), 
_firstname: firstName, 
_lastname: lastName)
```

But your declared init method is:

```
init(_objectId :  String ,
_pushId : String?,
_createdAt : Date,
_updatedAt : Date, 
_coins : Int,
_firstName: String,
_lastName:String,
_fullName:String,
_avatar:String,
_phoneNumber:String)
```

Not the same thing. You can include the extra elements in your call or provide default values in the signature.

e.g

```
init(_objectId :  String ,
_pushId : String?,
_createdAt : Date,
_updatedAt : Date, 
_coins : Int = 0,
_firstName: String,
_lastName:String,
_fullName:String = "",
_avatar:String = "",
_phoneNumber:String = "")
```

Also get your spelling right as called `_firstname` is not the same as the signature `_firstName`.

Also a style point. The `_` character is special within method signatures so while `_firstName` is a legal signature it will be confusing as heck for any future reader. Did you intend to use `_ firstName: String` with the intention of making the argument name not required? or just `firstName: String` which would be a normal style.